# Debug website on UC Browser for Windows Phone (UC Web)

Tags: css, responsive-design, windows-phone, uc-browser

I have a website which is working fine on all devices I've being testing, BUT, I'm having some problems in the UC Web (UC Browser) version for Windows Phone

Here is a screen of the problem:

[image]

And this is the same URL on Edge on the same device:

[image]

As you see, the grid and layout is not working.
I installed UC Web app in Windows (desktop) and I don't see the same problem, I also try it on the Android app version and still don't see that problem. Fast Mode on the app is disabled.
I just can't reproduce it in order to try to fix it.
Any idea how I can emulate this in order to try to fix it?

Comment: Does UC use the Edge rendering engine now? Unless my info is out of date, it's possible it still uses the IE11 engine - you could see if you get the same results with that.

Comment: @Katana314 yes! thank you! thats what i need to know. Couldnt find that UC use Edge engine, i can reproduce the error on IE.